# Is it possible to list all available signals in a given Flask app?

Tags: python, signals, flask

Is it possible to get a list of all signals that a given Flask app (with whatever additional packages have been added) may send? (i.e. and therefore can be subscribed to?)

Or does a Flask app / the Flask framework not know until when a signal is sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously accepted answer (by Sean Vieira) doesn't work for the latest version of Blinker (1.4) on Python 3.

To get all available signals (validated working on 1.4 and 1.3), you should

```py
from blinker import signal

all_signals = signal.__self__.keys()
```

Comment: 8 years later! @bluesummers do you know if it still worked on v1.3? If so, please add that and then I will accept this answer.

Comment: Yep, I just tested this on 1.3, the `signal.__self__.keys()` is the way to go in  1.3 as well

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that all of the packages create their signals when imported (and assuming you have imported all of the packages you care about) you should be able to introspect all of the named signals created via blinker.signal by iterating over it.  `blinker.signal` is a subclass of [`weakref.WeakValueDictionary`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/weakref.html#weakref.WeakValueDictionary), so you can simply call `keys` on it to get all of the names of the signals:

```
from blinker import signal
# import everything else here

print sorted(signal.keys())
```

See: [`blinker.base`](https://bitbucket.org/jek/blinker/src/f8045f98383c55c45bb7b5f9f8d2b21550df1645/blinker/base.py?at=default) for more information.

Comment: Note: this has been superseded; will work on earlier versions.